# Is it possible to gain strength by imagining working out?

Tags: physiology, visualization

Is it possible to still gain muscle strength by performing exercises but without load? Is there some kind of memory mechanism that would allow this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Visualization has psychological benefits that can assist well being, but will not increase muscle fibers.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is a duplicate, but let me know if there is any major difference.